# Wife applying for UK visa after husband got the decision?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, premium-services

I've applied for a UK standard visitor(priority) visa this week to visit my daughter who has ILR. I might get the decision in the next few days, but now my daughter wants her mum(my wife) to join me in the UK trip. Can I apply for my wife's standard visitor visa(priority) now? In my application I didn't mention she might be traveling with me, will this be counted as deception? I don't want to get in trouble. Please help me if anyone has experience?

Comment: Did you list your wife as a dependent? If the fact that she was to remain behind in your home country was material to your application, you may find that UKVI cancel your own visa if she applies. Do you / your wife have a prior travel history to the UK? What ties to your home country do you have if you travel together?

Comment: Hello, Yes I listed my wife as my dependant, I also have a married son and minor daughter who is in school, my parents, not traveling with me so they will be my home ties, my wife is financially dependent on me but we both own property each in our name and no neither of us have any previous travel history.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your wife is honest in her application and mentions that you have already applied (and gives all details like the numbers of the case) you will not get in trouble for deception. Plans change and officers will understand that your daughter did ask for her mother after you had applied.

But the case of your wife is much less strong than yours. In your case you had your wife as tie to your home country, in the case of your wife there will be no spouse left at home and the only ties are the much weaker ones of parents and an adult son.

So it may turn out you get your positive result and your wife does not, or it may be that you both get your visa. We have no way to predict what the result will be.

(If you have gotten the visa before I posted this answer, please come in and post what the results were.)